# How to get column names of all nonnull row values?

Tags: python, pandas

given a following dataframe

```
    A   B   C
0   1   Nan Nan
1  Nan  2   Nan
2  Nan  Nan 3
```

I want to get a column that gets all the column names of non null rows

expected result

```
   A   B   C   D
0   1   2 Nan   [A,B]
1  Nan  2   4   [B,C]
2   4  Nan 3    [A,C]
```

Would there be any solution using python?

Comment: df.notna().dot(df.columns+',').str.rstrip(',')

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df['D'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().index.to_list(), axis=1)
```

Comment: For performance is not nice this solution, but working.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with columns names with separator, remove last separator and splitting:

```
df['new'] = df.notna().dot(df.columns+',').str[:-1].str.split(',')
print (df)
     A    B    C     new
0  1.0  2.0  NaN  [A, B]
1  NaN  2.0  4.0  [B, C]
2  4.0  NaN  3.0  [A, C]
```

If performance is important use list comprehension with mask converted to numpy:

```
cols = df.columns.to_numpy()
df['new'] = [cols[x] for x in df.notna().to_numpy()]
```

Solution from comments is fine, if need joined values by `,`:

```
df['new'] = df.notna().dot(df.columns+',').str.rstrip(',') 
print (df)
     A    B    C  new
0  1.0  2.0  NaN  A,B
1  NaN  2.0  4.0  B,C
2  4.0  NaN  3.0  A,C
```

**Performance**:

```
#30k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/69704953/2901002
In [78]: %timeit df['D'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().index.to_list(), axis=1)
3.24 s ± 87.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

```
In [79]: %timeit df['new'] = df.notna().dot(df.columns+',').str[:-1].str.split(',')
45.7 ms ± 1.75 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [80]: %%timeit
    ...: cols = df.columns.to_numpy()
    ...: df['new'] = [cols[x] for x in df.notna().to_numpy()]
    ...: 
32.2 ms ± 3.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: @MuhammadHassan - btw, really surprised it is so slow, I think performance shoud be better in your solution, but not, is slow.

Comment: Yes, its very slow, I am also surprised.